# Automatically validate form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I wrote this code for validating form:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.each($(this).find('.required'), function(i,d){
        var lName = '#'+$(d).attr('for'); 
        if (!$(lName).val()) {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(d).offset().top }, 'slow');
            $(d).css({'color': '#ff0954'});
            if ($(lName).attr('class') == 'ckeditor') {

            }else{
                for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
                    $(lName).fadeTo('fast', 0.5).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

my code will search in `label` tags with `reqiured` class name and will validate field.

Every thing seems to be ok, but I have some problems:

1. I use `return false;` when field have problem, but the form will be submit .
2. I cannot `focus` on `ckeditor` class
3. I cannot validate `radio`, `checkbox` and `select` tags

Comment: Instead of writing jQuery Validation from scratch, why not use a very excellent plugin like this one?  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sparky , I will use [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) instance of I wrote from scratch :
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

## 1

Try setting a variable to true before the each loop. Then, where you have return false, set that variable to false. After the loop, check for that variable, and if it's false, return false. You're returning false on the each function right now, and you need to do it on the submit.

So something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var valid = true;
    $.each($(this).find('.required'), function(i,d){
        // all your checks
        // if your checks are bad
        valid = false;
    });
    if (valid === false) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

## 2

What is ckeditor? Can we see your full htmll?

## 3

What are you trying to validate? @sparky's comment is probably the right answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
    $("#myForm").validate();
});
```

here [jQuery validate documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Greetings...

Comment: That's a plugin, right? Not standard jQuery, and it has documentation somewhere?